# A proofy problem related to Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

Let f be a differentiable function that is continuous on $[a,b]$. 
Show that if there is a number $c$ where $a < c \leq b$ such that $f'(c) = 0$, 
then there is a number j where $a < j < b$ such that $f'(j) = \frac{f(j)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Is this something that involve the converse of mean value theorem?
How should one go about this question?

Things I have speculated upon:

c = b

f(j) = f(b)

f is a line

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already the first line has a trivial condition: **any differentiable** function is continuous...

Comment: Yea I thought it's a bit redundant too.

Comment: Can you check your required condition on $f'(j)$? It must be $f(a)$ surely, and is the denominator $(b-a)$ right?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Maybe it's supposed to be “differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$”?

Comment: The MVT assumes that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable inside $(a,b)$. Differentiability in $[a,b]$ suffices, too. Continuity at endpoints ensures the graph doesn't make any sudden jumps in which case it would be very easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm sure the problem is correct

Comment: I think you should check. $\frac{f(j)-(a)}{b-a}$ makes no sense. I suspect it is $\frac{f(j)-f(a)}{j-a}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have checked and the problem contains no error. It would certainly be convenient and much easier if it's talking about the secant slope.

Comment: @AlvinLepik One needs something to get the tangent the same as the chord to $(a,f(a))$?

Comment: If it can be done it can be done with $a<j<c$, so I'd amend that too.

Comment: @Lin25 If $f$ was a line, there would be no extrema unless $f$ was constant in which case the claim is obviously true.

Comment: Apply the MVT on the interval $[a,c]$. Then you can see the difference of the sides of the equation changes signs. Then you need yet another clever trick.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry, upvoted your attempted correction just for the $f(a)$ instead of $(a)$. I didn't pay attention to the denominator, which was correct to start with. Lin25 misread it the opposite way.

Comment: oh sorry for the error, it is $f(j)-f(a)$ I will fix that, I thought you were pointing out the denominator

Comment: @AlvinLepik yea the straight line answer was like a "maybe this is a trick question" desperate answer

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $f(c)>f(a)$. Let $d\in[a,c]$ satisfy $f(d)=\max\{f(x)\mid x\in[a,c]\}$. Then there is some $e\in(a,d)$ such that
$$ f'(e) = \frac{f(d)-f(a)}{d-a} \ge \frac{f(e)-f(a)}{b-a}. $$
On the other hand,
$$ f'(c) = 0 < \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{b-a}. $$
It follows that there is some $j\in[e,c)$ such that $f'(j)=\frac{f(j)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

I left the details as an exercise. The last line needs a little trick with two well-known theorems.